# Merge Pandas with fill empty cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge/join 2 tables in pandas on the basis of a key, but some of which do not exist in the 2nd table . The 2 tables look somewhat like this:

```
ID ATTR1 ATTR2
A1 2000 30
A2 300 12
A3 45 22

ID ATT12SUMCOND
A1 2030 
A2 312
```

Now the key value A3 does not exist in the second table, still I need to join these 2 tables somewhat like:

```
ID ATTR1 ATTR2 ATTR12COND
A1 2000 30   2030 
A2 300 12   312 
A3 45 22    0
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas' merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) method and then replace `NaN` values with 0 as follows-

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='ID').fillna({'ATTR12COND':0})
```

If you need to replace all `NaN` columns with 0, you can change [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) as follows-

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='ID').fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If no problem floats in new aded column replace missing values after [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left').fillna({'ATT12SUMCOND':0})
print (df)
   ID  ATTR1  ATTR2  ATT12SUMCOND
0  A1   2000     30        2030.0
1  A2    300     12         312.0
2  A3     45     22           0.0
```

Or use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for integer column:

```
df = df1.join(df2.set_index('ID').reindex(df1['ID'], fill_value=0), on='ID')
print (df)
   ID  ATTR1  ATTR2  ATT12SUMCOND
0  A1   2000     30          2030
1  A2    300     12           312
2  A3     45     22             0
```